# check if id exist in database if not redirect to my add cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

thanks see I have this problem I want to check if my id (of my user), exist into a other table  if this not exist redirect to my add.

> table1

### | users |

| id             |

| username       |

| password       |

| creation       |

| type           |

> table2

### |   user_azucar      |

| id                 |

| id_user            |

| cant               |

| medaza             |

| cachaza            |

I don't want to use hasone because is not for this case.

I want compare id==id_user exist a session for this.
controller

```
class IngeniosController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Ingenio');
        $conditions = array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserAzucar.id_user' => $this->Session->read('User.id')
            )
        );
        $result = $this->User->find('first', $conditions);
        if (isset($result['User'])){
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        }
    }
    public function delete()
    {

    }
}
```

model

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Ingenio extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'UserAzucar';
    public $useTable = 'usuarios_azucar';
    public $primaryKey = 'id_azucarusuario';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table2 is `user_azucar` or `usuarios_azucar`?

And why the model Name is different from the `$name` attribute?

You are using strange conventions for your names (why don't you follow cake conventions?)

but if I understand your schema then you have to do this:

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id_user' => $this->Session->read('User.id')
     )
);

$result = $this->Ingenio->find('first', $conditions);

if (empty($result)){
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the controller with the below code

```
class IngeniosController extends AppController { 
public function add()
{

}
public function index(){
    $this->loadModel('User');
$result_count = $this->User->find('count', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
        'table' => 'user_azucar',
        'alias' => 'UserAzucar',
        'type' => 'RIGHT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'UserAzucar.id_user = User.id'
        )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'UserAzucar.id_user' => $this->Session->read('User.id')
    )
    ));
    if(!$result_count){
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
    }
}
public function delete()
{

}
```

}

Comment: I did it but i have this error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object Line: 18"  $result_count I'm trying to solve this

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if SESSION has been loaded into your AppController and also in top of your Controller(This case you make sure that SESSION is not empty).

do this in your appController and top of IngeniosController

```
public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');
```

1. debug your SESSION to make sure if it is not empty

   ```
   var_dump($this->Session->read('User.id'));
   ```
2. Your controller:

   ```
   public function index()
   {
       $this->loadModel('UserAzucar');
       $conditions = array(
           'conditions' => array(
               'id_user' => $this->Session->read('User.id')
           )
       );
       $this->UserAzucar->recursive = -1;
       $result = $this->UserAzucar->find('first', $conditions);
       if (empty($result)){
           return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
       }
   }
   ```